# How do I design a notification system to be used across multiple websites?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, notifications

Some background: We have 3 websites that are all part of a standard workflow.  Each website handles a different part of the workflow.

- Website 1 is for sales (pricing, sales, etc)
- Website 2 is for engineers (implementation, coding, testing)
- Website 3 is for reporting (used by all but primarily for administration and management)

We're gearing up to add notifications in a way that's a lot like how StackOverflow does notifications.  I actually [posted this on Meta Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194403/how-does-stack-overflow-manage-notifications-and-templates) because that seemed like the best route, but the question didn't get very far.  The notifications in our context would be things like "John Smith's timesheet is late" or "You have been assigned to a project"

Now I'm curious as to how other developers have set this up.  I'm primarily worried about code repetition and maintenance at this stage.

Specifically, should each website be responsible for implementing its own notification client?  That seems like it'd be really easy for code bases to get out of sync.  But at the same time, even if you build a library you still need to handle the HTML templates somehow.  How much duplication of functionality is acceptable?  I'm at a loss here.

As you can tell, I'm not really sure where to start.  If this were for a single website it'd be a different story, but implementing it across multiple websites at the same time has be puzzled.

Some miscellaneous facts about our stack:

- Server side: ASP.NET MVC 4 (C#)
- Cliebnt side: jQuery + Knockout
- Database side: SQL Server w/ LINQ to SQL
- IE not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do something like [google +1 button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/). Link to a javascript common to everybody and have a custom html tag that will indicate where to put the data with configuration if needed.

Since you own all the websites, you can put everything in it's own .dll and add it to the solution of each solution.

Comment: This is actually pretty clever, I like this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Are you need something like Redis.io? There is Publish-subscribe in Redis.io.

Comment: The answer is technically yes, but what I'm more interested in is how I would implement a Redis client with as little duplication as possible.